# Determine an empty event loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to determine if there is an empty event loop?

For example,

```
// Example 1
setInterval(() => console.log("hi"), 1000);
// event loop is not empty


// Example 2
console.log("hi");
// event loop is now empty
```

Comment: There’s no documented built-in API. What do you need it for?

Comment: @Ryan: I want to exit a process once the event loop is empty.

Comment: Node exits automatically in that case.

Comment: You mean empty *event queue* rather than *event loop*, right?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> I want to exit a process once the event loop is empty

Node.js got you covered. Node process will exit automatically when the event-loop is empty.

---

If you opened this question because your tests (using Jest) were hanged for some reason, it means that the event loop was not empty at the end of all the `afterEach` and `afterAll` hooks, so if you are running a single test-file, Jest will usally hang. If you are running multiple tests files, jest will print an error which indicated that Jest forced to (not-gracefully) close the node-process of one of the test-files.

To fix that, make sure you don't forget to await to any promise, close all conections and clear all timeouts.